# Remove left alignment option in core/image block

Tags: filters, javascript, block-editor

I’m trying this code to disable the left alignment option from the `core/image` block. I just want to make available the center and right alignment options.

```js
wp.hooks.addFilter(
  'blocks.registerBlockType',
  'elvismdev/my-theme',
  function( settings, name ) {
    if ( name === 'core/image' ) {
      // Change supports
      settings.supports = lodash.merge( {}, settings.supports, {
        align: ['center', 'right']
      });
  }

return settings;
});
```

However, instead of doing what I’m expecting, it is adding a new alignment selector option to the block with only the center and right options, keeping the other default one with all of them (left, center, right).

[image]

Is `blocks.registerBlockType` the right filter to do it, or I’m missing something else?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an outstanding issue with the image block - visit https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/19103 to follow its progress.